# remove HTML tags from cell strings : excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Data with HTML tags in excel sheet like below:

```
<b>This is test data<br>Nice
<div> Go on this is next Cell
Very goood <b>.....</b>
```

SO, Basically I want to delete or replace all html tags with space in excel sheet.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Apply `Replace All` with `<*>` pattern:

[image: replace tags pattern]

To open this go to Ribbon `Home > Find & Select > Replace...` or simply press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Extra spaces may be further removed using `TRIM` function. Good luck!

Comment: You may add to `Replace with:` a space or anything, or left as is to be tags simply removed.

Answer (score 5):

Open VBA in Excel (Alt +F11), click on the project name (spreadsheet name) in the project explorer on the right. Insert -> New Module. Paste the user defined function below into the module Window. Save as .XLSM which allow Macros.

type the function '=StripHTML(A2)' assuming your data is in cell A2. You can also download a working example here:

http://jfrancisconsulting.com/how-to-strip-html-tags-in-excel/

```
Function StripHTML(cell As Range) As String
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Dim sInput As String
    Dim sOut As String
    sInput = cell.Text

    sInput = Replace(sInput, "\x0D\x0A", Chr(10))
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "\x00", Chr(10))

    'replace HTML breaks and end of paragraphs with line breaks
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "</P>", Chr(10) & Chr(10))
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "<BR>", Chr(10))

    'replace bullets with dashes
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "<li>", "-")

    'add back all of the special characters
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&ndash;", "–")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&mdash;", "—")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&iexcl;", "¡")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&iquest;", "¿")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&quot;", "")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&ldquo;", "")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&rdquo;", "")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "", "'")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&lsquo;", "'")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&rsquo;", "’")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&laquo;", "«")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&raquo;", "»")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&nbsp;", " ")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&amp;", "&")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&cent;", "¢")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&copy;", "©")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&divide;", "÷")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&gt;", ">")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&lt;", "<")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&micro;", "µ")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&middot;", "·")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&para;", "¶")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&plusmn;", "±")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&euro;", "€")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&pound;", "£")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&reg;", "®")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&sect;", "§")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&trade;", "™")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&yen;", "¥")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&aacute;", "á")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Aacute;", "Á")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&agrave;", "à")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Agrave;", "À")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&acirc;", "â")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Acirc;", "Â")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&aring;", "å")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Aring;", "Å")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&atilde;", "ã")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Atilde;", "Ã")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&auml;", "ä")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Auml;", "Ä")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&aelig;", "æ")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&AElig;", "Æ")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&ccedil;", "ç")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Ccedil;", "Ç")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&eacute;", "é")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Eacute;", "É")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&egrave;", "è")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Egrave;", "È")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&ecirc;", "ê")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Ecirc;", "Ê")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&euml;", "ë")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Euml;", "Ë")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&iacute;", "í")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Iacute;", "Í")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&igrave;", "ì")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Igrave;", "Ì")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&icirc;", "î")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Icirc;", "Î")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&iuml;", "ï")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Iuml;", "Ï")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&ntilde;", "ñ")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Ntilde;", "Ñ")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&oacute;", "ó")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Oacute;", "Ó")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&ograve;", "ò")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Ograve;", "Ò")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&ocirc;", "ô")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Ocirc;", "Ô")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&oslash;", "ø")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Oslash;", "Ø")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&otilde;", "õ")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Otilde;", "Õ")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&ouml;", "ö")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Ouml;", "Ö")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&szlig;", "ß")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&uacute;", "ú")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Uacute;", "Ú")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&ugrave;", "ù")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Ugrave;", "Ù")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&ucirc;", "û")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Ucirc;", "Û")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&uuml;", "ü")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&Uuml;", "Ü")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "&yuml;", "ÿ")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "", "´")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "", "`")

    'replace all the remaining HTML Tags
    With RegEx
    .Global = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "<[^>]+>" 'Regular Expression for HTML Tags.

    End With
    sOut = RegEx.Replace(sInput, "")
    StripHTML = sOut
    Set RegEx = Nothing
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the macro above didn't work for me I fixed it myself. It's my first script, if you guys can improve it, make it faster, add more then you're more than welcome!

Ok guys, I've had no previous experience programming (except for some very basic Java 6 years ago) but with some help, lots of guessing (hours actually) I managed to make this script, it works like a charm to remove most  and 8#text but it does not replace `<BR>` with linebreak (you can do this by hitting CTRL + H, "find: `<br>`" "replace: (now hold ALT down and use type 0010 with your NUMPAD. A small dot should be blinking in the replace window, then hit "replace all").

Paste the code below into a user module (alt +f11, right click Sheet1->insert->Module->paste code)

And make a button by going File->Options->Customize Ribbon-> check the Developer checkbox. Then go to developer tab->Insert->Button-> then place the button and right click->assign macro-> Choose RemoveTags.

```
Sub RemoveTags()
    Dim r As Range

    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"  'set cells to text numberformat

    With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
      .Pattern = "\<.*?\>"
      .Global = True

      For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = Replace(.Replace(r.Value, ""), "&#8217;", " ")
        r.Value2 = Replace(.Replace(r.Value2, ""), "&#8211;", " ")
      Next r

      For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = Replace(.Replace(r.Value, ""), "&#8216;", " ")
        r.Value2 = Replace(.Replace(r.Value2, ""), "&#8232;", " ")
      Next r

      For Each r In Selection
        r.Value = Replace(.Replace(r.Value, ""), "&#8233;", " ")
        r.Value2 = Replace(.Replace(r.Value2, ""), "&#146;s", " ")
      Next r
    End With
End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

End Sub
```