# magento product description unclosed html tags

Tags: html, magento, tags

I have thousands of html codes in excel file, including missing and unclosed html tags. Around 500K product descriptions. These unclosed html tags causes problems with the other static html blocks.

Is there a way to fix unclosed tags automatically. Or is there a way to close tag connections of product description using like custom html tags?

It looks impossible to fix this problem manually.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post a few examples of the HTML code in question, and describe what your expectations of a fixed version of them are.

Comment: you can check below link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705605/remove-html-tags-from-cell-strings-excel-formula hope it will be usable for you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: or you can copy only description column in excel sheet  and use find and replace and replace with empty spaces. but disadvantage is description will look like paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use/import them as product descriptions within Magento. You can use some PHP implementation to clean the output, or better: create a one-time script to loop all products and update their HTML description with a cleaned one.

Check out these HTML repair/clean tools:

- [PHP Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php)
- [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org)