# Remove all CSS from Excel cell

Tags: excel

So I have an exported file, but this consists of the entire "CSS code" in the value. I would like to remove the entire CSS value out of the Excell cells.

For example:

```
<span style="font-size:14px;"><span style="font-family:courier 
new,courier,monospace;">Hippe kaartjes - leuk voor jezelf, om cadeau te 
geven of als extraatje bij je bestelling!<br />Op de achterkant is er plek 
voor tekst of een adres.<br /><br />Het leuke van de kaartjes is dat je ze 
ook als woonaccesoire kunt gebruiken<br />- aan een mooie woonketting<br />- 
op een plankje met fotolijst<br />- met design tape<br /><br /><strong>Merk: 
</strong>ontworpen door Kidooz<br /><strong>Afmeting: </strong>A6<br /> 
<strong>Materiaal: </strong>300 grams papier</span></span>
```

Should be:
Hippe kaartjes - leuk voor jezelf, om cadeau te geven of als extraatje bij je bestelling!Op de achterkant is er plek voor tekst of een adres.Het leuke van de kaartjes is dat je ze ook als woonaccesoire kunt gebruiken- aan een mooie woonketting- op een plankje met fotolijst- met design tapeMerk: ontworpen door KidoozAfmeting: A6Materiaal: 300 grams papier

I have thought about replacing everything that starts with "<" and ends with ">". I am not able to make the correct code in Excel though.

Can you guys help me out please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14705605/remove-html-tags-from-cell-strings-excel-formula

Answer (score 1):

The more easy way is just to replace the extra data.
Ctrl+F and then click on the replace tab.

Find what: `<*>`
Replace with:

The "replace with" field should be totally empty and voila!