# remove multiple enters using vba - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

This question is asked many times may be its same but I haven't found particular solution for this.

I have ms access database there are some field with '`Long Text`' Text format '`Rich Text`'

I have created one Macro in Excel which use this database and get the value from those fields. After getting the value in excel it shows me string with Html tags.

I am using following function copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17172724/1521171). which is good remove all tags but it gives me output as follows

before function:

```
<div>xxxxxxx ccccccccd eeerr sdff aerderfng</div>

<div>&nbsp;</div>

<div>xxxxxx rrrrrr</div>

<div>-&gt; V.tredf</div>
```

after applying function

```
xxxxxxx ccccccccd eeerr sdff aerderfng



xxxxxx rrrrrr

-> V.tredf
```

I would like to remove those extra line break or Enters from the final output. I am struggling with this.

My desire output what i would like to have is like this

```
"xxxxxxx ccccccccd eeerr sdff aerderfng
xxxxxx rrrrrr
-> V.tredf"
```

Comment: Is what you want a string in an Excel cell, or three consecutive rows? I do not have time to see the 'function'...

Comment: According code you linked please consider using  `sInput = Replace(sInput, vbNewLine, "")     sInput = Replace(sInput, Chr(10), "")    sInput = Replace(sInput, Chr(13), "")   and so on.`

Comment: @FaneDuru I would like to have in one cell. 3 line output represent one cell as per above example

Comment: @barneyos I have tried this it will make a string together. without any enter

Comment: This in code     `'replace HTML breaks and end of paragraphs with line breaks
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "</P>", Chr(10) & Chr(10))
    sInput = Replace(sInput, "<BR>", Chr(10))` add new lines. Maybe try without it.

Comment: @Tarun.P:  Maybe my question was not clear enough... I wanted to refer at what your 'function' returns in Excel. In that Excel do you have, what you show above, in one Excel cell and the text must only be Trimmed, or do you have separate rows and in such a case, they must be deleted? But, I could see you received two answers. Did you test them?

Answer (score 0):

Just double your replacement chars, like this for example, multiple times, at the end only one newline will remain

```
Replace(sInput, vbNewLine & vbNewLine, vbNewLine)
Replace(sInput, Chr(13) & Chr(13), Chr(13))
Replace(sInput, Chr(10) & Chr(10), Chr(10))
Replace(sInput, Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10) &Chr(13), Chr(10) & Chr(13))
Replace(sInput, Chr(13) & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & Chr(10), Chr(13) & Chr(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegEx` like below to get rid of all such characters. Adopt it to suit your requirements.

```
Public Sub RemoveBlankNewLineChar()
    Dim rgEx As Object
    Set rgEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With rgEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "\n+"
        ' Adjust Selection part with suitable Excel Range References.
        Selection.Value = .Replace(Selection.Value, vbCrLf)
    End With
End Sub
```